Assistance Needed: Identifying Underground Pipes Found During Excavation
While working on some foundation projects and excavating soil, I encountered the following underground pipes:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hn7H8wedXGZBCgGeOXvCAlkny7GZ2ynE/view
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hp4bHyMta0mtzQ2nI93_5svBI3zLZMn3/view
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hpMeVZePG6Cb_-orDWmoOlKzR1Ay4C59/view
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hu6jPDmTiI6pU2fkykyL4UhM2qgDm2pW/view
Pipe Depth
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i0B3RQ6l5EzKJHzuZUbCEnRsfmOwYoCK/view?usp=sharing
There are two pipes situated next to each other at a depth of approximately 250mm. The auger scratched the surface of one of the pipes, revealing a black outer plastic layer and a shiny white metal-like material underneath.
There are no leaks; the pipes are simply wet from the weather. However, I am unable to determine if these pipes are for gas, water, or electricity.
Can anyone help identify these pipes? Is it safe to proceed with concreting over them?
Thanks

If close to your foundation, look at what service, if any, comes inside the foundation / basement near where you encountered them.

Only a foot deep with no marking/flagging above? How old is the house?

Please consider attaching the photos directly rather than linking to your Google Drive. You will get more views of the question.

Please call 811 (or whatever your digsafe/onecall number is) before you make any more moves involving those pipes!!!!!

You didn't give your location, but in my area (Eastern US) there is a free "DIG SAFE" service which will tell you where active utility pipes are before you even break ground. if something like this is available where you are, I'd highly recommend taking advantage of it.

Various other names I'm aware  of, varying with location: 811, blue stake, "Call before you dig" (though that phrase is usually pointing you at the number 811 or the dig safe number for your locale, rather than being a service name itself.)

FWIW, in my area they tend to use spray paint rather than stakes.
